# jenkins rest get duration in human format

Tags: rest, jenkins

I need to get job duration via curl command.

I can get access to it

curl -s $JENKINS_JOB_URL/146/api/json?tree=duration

{"duration":14182142}

How convert the 14182142 to "3 hr 56 min" ? ( via ksh, or in the curl command )

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You could always use some python:

```
python -c"import datetime;print datetime.timedelta(milliseconds=14182142);"
```

3:56:22.142000

Answer (score 2):

Is awk acceptible?

```
curl -s $JENKINS_JOB_URL/146/api/json?tree=duration | awk -F : '{ print $2 }' | awk -F } '{ printf "%i hr %i min", ($1 / 3600000), ($1 % 3600000)/60000 }'
```

If anyone knows of a nice way to get the number out of the string and into awk, I can remove the nasty double-invocation of awk.

Comment: how to get the time in hr min and seconds

Comment: Add "%i seconds" to the format string, then use the remainder and div functions to pull out the seconds: remainder from 60000, div by 1000.

Comment: duration=$(curl -g -u youssefboudaya:1159d3bdda500d6cc78bede1100245362a --silent "$BUILD_URL/api/json?pretty=true&tree=duration" | jq -r '.duration') gives me "0" as duration . i did it in post build task

Comment: Have you looked at the resulting JSON? Is the value that is coming back actually 0? Maybe 0 is correct?