# Jenkins: Get the completion or end time of previous build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

Is it possible to get previous build completion time in Jenkins pipeline?
And use it in next build. Instead of storing it in some file and then fetching for next build.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this way

```
currentBuild.rawBuild.getPreviousBuild().getTimestamp()
```

refer to http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Run.html#getTimestamp--

Answer (score 0):

The following pipeline prints the duration of the previous run of this pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    options {
        //keep only 10 last builds
        buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '10', artifactNumToKeepStr: '1'))
        disableConcurrentBuilds()
    }

    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh 'sleep 5';
            }
        }

        stage('Get time of previous build') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def duration = currentBuild.previousBuild.duration;
                    print duration;
                }
            }    
        }
    }

    post {
        always {
            cleanWs()
        }
    }
}
```

But the duration value will not be a 'human readable' value so you'll still need to convert the value using `awk` or `python`: explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23379374/jenkins-rest-get-duration-in-human-format).

Comment: The question was requesting completion time, not duration.

Comment: `previousEndTimeInMillis = currentBuild.previousSuccessfulBuild.startTimeInMillis + currentBuild.previousSuccessfulBuild.duration`. Then it must be converted to a human readable date, if required for display.